# How do I get OnSubmit to grab an external file?

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
 onsubmit="return validatePP(this);
```

I moved all of the validate function to an external file. How do I get it to call the external file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include it into your HTML file: `<script language="Javascript" src="[path]"></script>"`.

You'll also want to make sure that the script file is loaded prior to using the function (if you're loading synchronously, include the script tag before the script block that you call the validate function in).

Comment: is there anyway I can have it so it will check the external file?

Comment: You *could* dynamically load the script on first validate function call, but that's overkill and the implementation would be pretty ugly. The alternative would be to communicate to a server-driven page using AJAX.

Comment: @Kenshi: Maybe you could post your code so we can see where it's going wrong?